# How to show subfields in webservice response

Tags: java, web-services, hibernate

{"toDate": "2014/07/01","fromDate": "2014/05/01","imeiNo": "1234567890", 
 "phoneNumber": 1234567890,
 "emailId": “”
}

Response Packet:

```
{
  "ResponseCode": "M00110",
  "ResponseMessage": "Records found",
  "ResponseType": "01",
  "RequestData": [
    {
      "TxnId": 1,
      "Date": "2014/10/12",
      "Card": "888888345",
      "CardType": 1,
      "Bank": "",
       "Merchant Name": "ABC Corp",
      "Amount": "$250"
    },
    {
      "TxnId": 1,
      "Date": "2014/10/12",
      "Card": "88888345",
      "CardType": "",
      "Bank": "XYZ BANK",
       "Merchant Name": "ABC Corp",
      "Amount": "$250"
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Clarify your question again and the code you've tried!!

Comment: Your question is not clear on what you are trying to achieve and there is no code which you have tried ad what issue you are facing with it

Answer (score -1):

Response string can be converted to map or entity class using ObjectMapper Class of jackson library then the same map or entity class can be used to show the fields on jsp.

For example:-
Create entity for the response packet;

class ResponsePacket{

```
 List<RequestData> requestData;
```

}

then create the entity by:-

ResponsePacket responsePacket = new ObjectMapper().readValue(responseString, ResponsePacket.class);

in jsp:-

```
${data.txnId}
${data.date}
```